# Global state with Nextjs App router using zustand

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context, next.js13, zustand

Normally when I used zustand, I declared global zustand store and then directly called zustand hooks in client components in nextjs app router. But after watch this Jack Herrington's [Tutorial](https://www.pronextjs.dev/tutorials/state-management/zustand-for-state-management/state-management-with-zustand), I learned that we can't safely use Zustand hooks that are declared globally. We need to pass zustand hooks via react context api to prevent store collisions from multiple simultaneous requests receiving for App router. Are these steps actually neccessary? Actually can be cause any errors that if we use zustand hooks directly? Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is necessary. Redux have similar guidance

> The first change is to move from defining store as a global or module-singleton variable, to defining a makeStore function that returns a new store for each request

https://redux.js.org/usage/nextjs#creating-a-redux-store-per-request